# CSS issue on aligning of the event block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wonder how, using css (without javascript or else), make something.

I will have separate spans and divs for:

- MN (Monday - day of the week)
- 30 (Date)
- Sep (Month)
- and for the title

Maybe there's any framework to do that? Or could you please provide the example at least of less complicated variant with Date and Month displayed only.

(I'm using Twitter Bootstrap framework v2.3.2)

Comment: I've removed your link to imageshack, as it's dead. Consequently I'm also voting to close as unclear what you want. Please eventually re-illustrate your question properly with an embedded image.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple: set the display of each span/div to `table-cell` and `vertical-align` to `top`, `bottom` or `middle`. That, and set different fonts and sizes for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like That <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/5M8FK/1/)</kbd>

play with it, and adjust it to your needs, but this is the basic layout.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Row">
        <div><span>MN</span><span>30</span><span>Sep</span></div>
        <div>Some Event</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div><span>MN</span><span>30</span><span>Sep</span></div>
        <div>Some Event</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div><span>MN</span><span>30</span><span>Sep</span></div>
        <div>Some Event</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Container
{
    display: table;
    width: 500px;
    border-spacing: 20px;
}
.Row
{
    display: table-row;
}
.Row > div
{
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.Row span:first-child
{
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.Row span:nth-child(2)
{
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.Row span:nth-child(3)
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```